# configure wsgi python

Tags: python, django, amazon-ec2, mod-wsgi, virtual-machine

im configuring my EC2 instance (amazon web services) on an ubuntu server, to test django(python)

I have python installed, and the apache server,

I have the `It works!` [apache] page on my url address, index.html

now im  configuring the wsgi and mod_wsgi [for python and django],

im following this info to configure wsgi:

[deploy python wsgi app tutorial](http://library.linode.com/web-servers/apache/mod-wsgi/ubuntu-10.04-lucid)

but when I try the `Basic Hello World WSGI Configuration`

```
import os 
import sys 

sys.path.append('/srv/www/cucus/application') 

os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/srv/www/cucus/.python-egg' 

def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = 'Hello World!'
    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

and go to mysite/application/application.wsgi

> http://ec2-107-20-20-19.compute-1.amazonaws.com/cucus/application/application.wsgi

in my browser,
i see the code for the page, but not the rendered "hello world"

what im i missing?

do I need to configure the virtual hosts for ubuntu?, even im using just one site?

thanks!

Comment: Why would you go to the wsgi file itself in your browser? That's not how it works, otherwise all WSGI applications would have that in their URL.

Comment: @DanielRoseman , thanks, thats my question to, so why is this "application.wsgi" with code for hello world inside?, what url to use to test this hello world? code above, thanks!

Comment: You seem to have ignored the section in that tutorial headed "Configure Apache". Then go to the normal `/` (root) URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read any of the actual mod_wsgi documentation or watch the presentation about it:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide
  http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/WhereToGetHelp?tm=6#Conference_Presentations

You either never set up WSGIScriptAlias or didn't enable the site for Apache properly to read it or didn't restart Apache.

Answer (score 2):

You need your output to be binary.

Change

`output = 'Hello World!'`

to

`output = b'Hello World!'`

Here's some simple WSGI boilerplate code I created - show's you how to manage a GET and POST request.

https://github.com/blarking94/Python/blob/master/web_server_gateway_interface.py

Comment: This is not an answer to original persons issue. Back then they were likely using Python 2, not Python 3 so the WSGI application code would have been fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting Apache if that does not work then double your apache config you are enabling mod_wsgi with this line of code `LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so` as well as `WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mysite/apache/django.wsgi`